# Is there a way to turn unix commands as map reduce activities?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to get UNIX outputs in hive query.
For example the following query doesn't work:

```
select transform ('') 
using 'pwd' 
as syspath
```

But this query works:

```
select transform ('') 
using 'hive -e "select 10 as col1"' 
as col1
```

How do I enable UNIX commands or bash scripts as a map reduce job to gets its output available in hive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform) what you are looking for?

Comment: @franklinsijo I'm using transform operator to run unix commands and print it as query output.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Isn't that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yeah but unix commands aren't working. As I understand from the documentation you shared, the command in transform should be a map reduce job, so I guess a simple unix command won't work. In that case, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you please explain the use case?

Comment: I want to count the number of characters from a file and show that as an output of a hive query. I can frame a UNIX command for this but not sure how to output that in hive

Answer (score 0):

> count the number of characters from a file

Why would you ever use Hive for that? Spark is so much more flexible.

```scala
val charCount = spark.read.textLines("path/to/file.txt")
    .flatMap(line => line.toList())
    .map(char => (char, 1)) // This is literally just wordcount, now
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map((char, count) => count)
    .sum() // something like this ... 
println(charCount.collect()(0))
```